# insert SQL dummy column

Tags: sql, sql-server

HI there..

this is a bit hard to explain so i will show code of the update equivalent ..

```
   declare @dummy as int;
    UPDATE pages
    SET 
    @dummy = 0
,field ='asdsa' ... etc
```

because i am writing a code generator it gets messy trying to determine if a comma is needed or not..  i am having this problem with inserts now.. ive tried this dummy approach but doesnt work... is it possible to force an insert into a column that doesnt exist.. the @dummy works for update, so hoping there is a way for insert..

thanks heaps
A

Answer (score 1):

No way to do this on INSERT, unless you have a dummy column in each table.

Of course, my question now is why don't you have defaults and/or parametrization and/or use an ORM and/or use reflection-based solutions...